# Trilateration algorithm to position 3 circles as close as possible without overlapping

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry, computational-geometry

I have two circles that are positioned perfectly on the boarder of each other. They have position A and B (both vectors), and radii Ra and Rb.

Now I add a third circle with radii Rc. How can I find the position vector C where the three circles are placed as close as possible without overlapping?

I'm writing this for an illustration for a website I'm building, so bonus points for efficiency :)

Edit:
I didn't have enough rep to post an illustration when I originally posted.
Two of the circles (B and C) will be overlapping, but tangental to A. I want to move C out of the overlapping zone it shares with B, into the dotted line.

[image: Circles]

Edit 2:
I'm sorry it's been so unclear, I've created a diagram that tried to explain what I'm trying to do.

I'm creating an illustration in Pixi.js, a simple canvas/webGL library. I'm using Vectors (through Victor.js) to position the circles and move them around.

I randomly generate a bunch of circles, and then I position the biggest circle (A) in the middle of the container. After that I want to cluster all the circles around A, solving collisions as they happen. This is important as I'm going to be scaling individual circles when the user taps or hovers them.

For the simple case where nothing collided the vector solution was super simple, and I want solve the case where two circles collide in the same way if possible.

[image: Problem diagram]

Comment: Problem description is not clear.

Comment: There are 2 answers for C, you can't have 1 answer

Comment: Are the circles touching?

Comment: Any of the answers would work, but the closest one would be preferable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to find the point that forms a triangle with sides lengths: Ra+Rb, Ra+Rc, Rb+Rc. That's known as solving by three sides, but you'll get 2 possible answers.

The basic formula to use here is the law of cosines: **c^2 = a^2 + b^2 - 2ab*cos(gamma)**

Let define our lengths as:

1. La = Ra+Rb
2. Lb = Rb+Rc
3. Lc = Rc+Ra

We'll first find the angle between AB & AC. Solve `arccos(a) = (Lb^2 + Lc^2 - La^2) / 2*Lb*Lc`
*(If at this point you already have  the coordinate system angle of AB, you can skip to the 3rd step)*

The 2nd step is to find the coordinate system angle of AB relative to the X axis. This is done using basic trigonometry. Find the height `h = Ay - By`, and the angle is `arcsin(b) = h / La`.

The 3rd step is to either add or substract (2 answers!) angles a & b and that's the direction of a vector starting at point A where point C is located at a distance Lc. To find C, again use trigonometry.

`Cx = Ax + Lc * cos(a + b)`
`Cy = Ay + Lc * sin(a + b)`

Comment: I wish `SO` would allow MathJax formatting. Anyway this is the correct solution as you know three sides and are looking for an internal angle.

Comment: Hey Amit! How do I get in touch with you now? I can't reach you on Whats App
This is also correct! Sorry I didn't notice. However, I was hoping to find a clever way around doing many expensive trigonometric calculations as I want to try to animate the transformation.

Comment: @sindre - Sorry, you can't contact me on whatsapp, and generally, you're not supposed to directly contact anyone on SO. The idea is that you share your questions, corrections, answers and everything else on the site itself (using these comments when needed) so that everything is available for others to learn from / comment about. So, why are you fearring trig calcs? they're not "that" expensive for a single circle. If you want to animate something, please explain the animation you're trying to create...

Comment: @Amit sorry, I thought you were a personal friend of mine with the same name, who uses a similar avatar. His number seemed to be disconnected from What's App. My bad, sorry about that.
I have up to 10 circles that might be colliding at the same time in an animation, at 60fps I'm worried that 4 trig calculations per circle in a browser will lead to poor performance.
I'm going to try this now and see how it goes.

Comment: @sindre, no problem.. funny coincidence. I'm not sure I understand your scenrio though. You have 10 circles, and you're animating all of them? from what state to what state? and how is collision related to finding the end position? (BTW, circle collision detection is MUCH simpler than that)

Comment: I'm having some issues getting this done, maybe my approach is wrong. I'll explain what I'm trying to accomplish instead of the problem. I basically want to create some initial random configuration like this: http://imgur.com/saSzyWs
I don't care how this is done, I don't have to animate it.
Once the initial positions are set I'm going to make them interactive by clicking. When a circle is clicked I need to scale it 3x-5x to fit text inside it, and I need the other circles to move away so there's no overlap. I also need to scale it down when something else is clicked and keep them together.

Comment: Note: The scaling will be animated

Comment: That's mostly fine but I suggest you post a new question as it's completely different. Make sure you clarify what you expect the animation to be like (for example, where should the other circles move to...). you can post a comment on this question linking to the new one for follow-up.

Comment: Most people got this question right as it's pretty basic.. I'll use yours as it was the clearest, and for taking account of the rotation between the different axes. Thanks for your time Amit.

Answer (score 1):

When the circles touch each other, distance between centers is known as sum of radii. Solve this system of equations and find `Cx,Cy` coordinates. There are two possible solutions. Solution is simpler when coordinate origin is placed to the center of one circle.

```
(Cx-Ax)^2 + (Cy-Ay)^2 = (Ra+Rc)^2
(Cx-Bx)^2 + (Cy-By)^2 = (Rb+Rc)^2
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is simplified if you assume that the first circle (`A`) has center `(0,0)`, and the second circle (`B`) has center on the positive `x`-axis. If that's not the case, you can translate the center of `A` to `(0,0)` and then rotate the plane to make it the case. (Then at the end reverse those operations to restore the original configuration.)

Then the center of `C` is at a distance `A.R + C.R` from the center of `A`, and the center of `C` is at a distance `B.R + C.R` from the center of `B`, where `A.R`, `B.R`, `C.R` are the radii of circles `A`, `B`, `C`. In other words, the center of `C` lies on the intersection of the two circles

```
      x^2 + y^2 = (A.R + C.R)^2
(x-B.x)^2 + y^2 = (B.R + C.R)^2
```

where `(B.x,0)` is the center of circle `B`. Subtracting the first equation from the second we have

```
-2*B.x*x + B.x^2 = B.R^2 + 2*B.R*C.R - A.R^2 - 2*A.R*C.R
```

in other words, the center of `C` has `x` coordinate

```
C.x = (A.R^2 + 2*A.R*C.R + B.x^2 - B.R^2 - 2*B.R*C.R)/(2*B.x)
```

Now that we have `C.x`, we can easily calculate `C.y`:

```
C.y = plus or minus sqrt((A.R+C.R)^2 - C.x^2)
```

Now reverse the transformation you applied at the beginning, if any (first reverse the rotation, then reverse the translation), and you have the final center of `C`.

If you don't want to apply an initial translation and rotation, you can still solve the problem, of course, but the algebra is somewhat messier.

Comment: This seems like what I was looking for, I'll try to implement it and come back here. It's night in Oslo, so I'll build it first thing in the morning. Thanks:)